# Gravity Forms Notifications not being received on Google Workspace but are received everywhere else

Tags: wordpress, google-workspace, gravity-forms-plugin

I have set up gravity forms on my WordPress website and I do get e-mail notifications once someone fills the form. However, I am not being able to receive e-mails on one specific domain email addresses hosted on Google Work space. I have reviewed the workspace safety and privacy settings as well and didn't find anything out of place.

It is my good guess that this is a Google Workspace related issue and not a WordPress one. I would appreciate support from the community.

I have tried following tutorials on setting up Gravity Form notifications. I have also tried fiddling with Google Workspace safety settings.